# Xamarin dependency injection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin app that is Using FreshMVVm for the views and models.

I have a background worker class that I am trying to Inject my repository into.
The repository does not have an interface.

I am getting the following error.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Inventory.Repository' while attempting to activate 'Inventory.BackgroundWorker.BackGroundWorker'.'

This is my code for the Backgroundworker class

```
namespace Inventory.BackgroundWorker
{
    public class BackGroundWorker : IBackGroundWorker
    {
        private readonly Repository _repository;
        public BackGroundWorker(Repository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
     }
}
```

Do I need to add scope for repository in the startup.
How would I do this if it does not have an interface.

Comment: Have you registered your `Repository` class  with your ioc?

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: The Repository works in all my FreshMVVM  PageModels but not in this class

Comment: I am registering the repository in My main activity class in my Droid project. Should I move the background worker to that project then.

Comment: Well how you have Registered your ViewModels to FreshMvvm container your would similarly Register BackgroundWorker as well

Comment: No need to move it just Register it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248410/discussion-between-freakyali-and-stanton-roux).